# What is a document?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, document

that may be just the most stupid question ever, but I really can't find the answer anywhere.

Is "document" refers only to the HTML file or other files too? I mean, everywhere people refers to a document as a web page or HTML document, but isn't a JS or CSS file document too?

Sorry in advance, but I'm just starting and trying to understand the basic concepts and that is bothering me right now big time. I literally searched on multiple sites and two books about JavaScript and didn't find definitive answer.

Comment: See/Read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document

Comment: A Sumerian tablet is a document too. It's all about context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on MDN :
that is a web page loaded in the browser and serving as an entry point into the page's content.

in a not correct way , it's the same as your web page's compiled source code.